# Passing ID in GET request URL through Model class in Retrofit

Tags: java, android, json, api, retrofit2

This is the API URL for deleting a record

GET : localhost:4000/course/delete/5bd9a270c6a31620e0b7b3d8

5bd9a270c6a31620e0b7b3d8  is an ID which is there in server and model class. I want call an API and pass it dynamically to url for  deleting the record.

how to write an interface call request

```
@GET("course/delete/?id?") //how to write
Call<List<Course>> deleteRecords();
```

Responses will be appreciated

Comment: id is query parameter or path?

Comment: https://square.github.io/retrofit/2.x/retrofit/index.html?retrofit2/http/Path.html

Comment: how to find out. I am new into this. the postman link to this url is working fine

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Just do it:

```
@GET("course/delete/{id}")
Call<List<Course>> deleteRecords(@Path("id") String id);
```

And then call:

```
retrofit.deleteRecords("5bd9a270c6a31620e0b7b3d8");
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. but I am getting this error
 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: @Path parameter name must match \{([a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*)\}. Found: _id (parameter #1)
                                                               
I am calling by this. 

  Call<List<Course>> call = serviceRetro.deleteRecords(id);

Comment: in debug I have checked. id is properly getting the value

Comment: Just replace `@Path("_id")` to `@Path("id")` for parameter in `deleteRecords` method.

Answer (score 5):

Try this [definition](https://square.github.io/retrofit/2.x/retrofit/index.html?retrofit2/http/Path.html)

```
@GET("course/delete/{id}")
Call<List<Course>> deleteRecords(@Path("id") String id));
```